# MS SQL SERVER не работает AUTO INCREMENT

Tags: sql-server

Создал таблицу, через правую кнопку мыши указал primary key, при добавлении данных первичный ключ не заполняется автоматически и выдаёт ошибку что поле не может быть пустым, я всё перетыкал и нигде не нашёл в интерфейсе способа добавить эту функцию, что я сделал не так?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно указать, что столбец таблицы является IDENTITY.

Пожалуйста, смотрите ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]